# Web.Config values to be specific to release vs debug

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config

Is it possible to make some values in my Web.Config file dependent on whether I am building a release or debug based ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are looking for [web.config and transformation](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=vs2010%20web.con&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vs2010%20web.config%20transformation&gws_rd=ssl), it's part of [VS2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710063032/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/04/web-deployment-with-vs-2010-and-iis.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, but...

Using web.config transformations you can transform web.config for the deployment process. You can't use this for debugging purposes.

See my question on this topic.

[VS 2010 Web.config transformations for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990384/vs-2010-web-config-transformations-for-debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can [use XDT transforms](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621010228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx).