# Can web.config transformations be set to run on dev machines without a full publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, transform

We've got several devs working on a project and they keep checking their web.configs in with their own connection strings which is a pain.

Is there a way to kick off the TransformWebConfig task on a local machine when we do F5 debug? I've made a new configuration for my local machine but I can't figure out how to hack in the TransformWebConfig task.

Or is there a better way to isolate connection strings between dev machines?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this issue before, but found no way to do this. Here is the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990384/vs-2010-web-config-transformations-for-debugging) with an answer, including the reasons why this won’t work.

Second part of your question – better ways of isolating connection strings: In my view there are different approaches

- configSource for connection strings 
  and build-actions to copy the
  developer versions into the right
  places
- web transformations + remote
  debugging with a fake deployment  to
  a local IIS server
- a central database
  server for testing, to keep the
  developers connection strings
  constant