# Is it possible to perform Web.config transformations without publishing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, build-process, build-automation

I am using VS2010, and I understand that when I publish a web application, the Web.config I am using is transformed based on the build settings.

i.e. When I choose Debug, it uses my development SQL server, and when I choose Release, it uses my production SQL server.

What I want to know is: Can I, using only the built in Visual Studio Development Server, select "Release" from the Configuration drop-down, and then the green "Continue" arrow (F5), and run using the transformed Web.config settings?

I would be quite happy having another file such as "generic.config" (or better: "Web.Generic.config"), which holds the master code if necessary.

Comment: Here are the answers I get a time ago on a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990384/vs-2010-web-config-transformations-for-debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's a simple way to do this. I would have thought it's unusual to want to run code locally against a production database, but maybe you're not in Enterprise Land which is probably what this functionality was designed for.

An alternative would be to publish your site to a server, and then use Remote Debugging to step into the code.

The plain `web.config` is your local and generic settings combined. The transforms tweak the generic data to match the environment you're deploying to.

There's a handy site if you just want to quickly test the results of a web.config transform: http://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com