# Web config setting for deployment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

In my web.config file, I have a connection string to connect my development database.

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="MembershipDB" connectionString="Data Source=DebugSQL;Initial Catalog=PortalAccess;Integrated Security=True;Application" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

When I publish the web site to my production server, I just change the Data Source name.
When I test it, then I switch it again, is it stupid?

Comment: It is not stupid, since it works, however it could be better. Since you are using Visual Studio, I would set up web transforms: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx ... and have a web.config for development and one for release. Solves the problem nicely.

Comment: If I use .net 3.5, is ot okay?

Comment: It's an IDE feature rather than Framework feature, so if you have Visual Studio 2010 or later you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common approach and can work well.

Obviously you can run into problems if you get the details wrong while maintaining it by hand this way.

You could also have a look into web.config transformations: This is a way of writing a main web.config file and then writing separate files that change the original depending on the build configuration you run.

Some resources:

- [Related question on StackOverflow;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990384/vs-2010-web-config-transformations-for-debugging)
- [Asp.Net tutorial;](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-introduction-1-of-12)
- [MSDN Video for VS 2010.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff801895.aspx)